# Proving relation between exponential generating functions whose coefficients count certain types of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Let's there be two exponential generating functions:
$A(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$
$B(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{b_n}{n!}x^n$
Sequence ${\{a_n\}}^\infty_{n=1}$ defines number of all possible simple graphs on n labelled vertices.
Sequence ${\{b_n\}}^\infty_{n=1}$ defines number of all possible simple **connected** graphs on n labelled vertices.
I am trying to prove the following relationship between these two generating functions:
$A(x)=e^{B(x)}-1$
The expression for $a_n$ is easy to derive: $a_n=2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, but I don't know how to demonstrate the equation above.
I found the following hint for this problem:
It can be shown that $\frac{(B(x))^k}{k!}$ is the exponential generating series for the labelled graph with exactly k components.

Comment: Hi, do you know how does $B(x)^k$ looks like? Remember that the multiplication principle says that you will get a sequence of the objects in $B$ but because they are graphs, the order is irrelevant and so you divide by $k!$ to have a bunch of unorder connected components.

Comment: @Phicar But this is a labelled graph.

Comment: It does not matter, the labels are on the vertices, not in the components. if the graph has as components $\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}$ as nodes. it is the same as  $\{4,5\},\{1,2,3\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A further HINT: The hint tells you that

$$e^{B(x)}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\big(B(x)\big)^k}{k!}\,,$$

so

$$e^{B(x)}-1=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{\big(B(x)\big)^k}{k!}\,.$$

A simple graph on $n$ vertices has at least one component, so . . .

You may find Problem $413$ of [this web page](https://bogart.openmathbooks.org/ctgd/app3-5-expformula.html) or  Section $4$ of [this PDF](https://www.math.toronto.edu/balazse/2019_Fall_MAT344/Lec_10.pdf) helpful.

Comment: I understand how hint implies expression $e^{B(x)}-1$, what is not clear for me it the nature of summand $\frac{(B(k))^k}{k!}$, more specifically where denominator comes from.

Comment: @AveryPrometheis: It’s the same labelled graph no matter in which of the $k!$ possible orders you list the components.